# Qualtrics Loop & Merge: Display all selected answer choices in one matrix table?

Tags: qualtrics

I understand how loop and merge works, but I can't find any examples that display the results altogether in one question.

What I want is for the user to select all that apply from a multi-select question:
[image: Example]

Then instead of displaying each selected answer in a separate question (as shown in the [Qualtrics docs](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/blocks-and-block-options/loop-and-merge/#LoopAndMergeFields)) I'd rather all of their selected choices be displayed in one Matrix Table so that the user can rate each individually.

[image: Result Example]

Is this even possible? I'm assuming if so it will require some kind of loop in Javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Only way I can see this happening is hard coding all of the possible selections into the matrix, then applying display logic on each answer option.

Comment: @AnthonyTJRivas I didn't realize you could add display logic on individual answer choices. This will definitely work then, although a little more effort/potential for error than I'd like. Thanks for bringing this option to my attention!

Comment: What does loop & merge have to do with these two questions? It doesn't appear to be something that is needed in your example. Putting aside loop & merge, you can use "Carry forward statements" in the second question to display the choices selected in the first question.  Since you have open ends in the first question, you'll want to use "Selected Choices - Entered Text" as the carry forward.

Comment: @T.Gibbons Perfect! That works great. I am just getting into the more advanced functions that Qualtrics offers. I just assumed Loop & Merge was what I needed to use, but "Carry Forward" is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh even better, I assumed you were using loop and merge for something else! That should work great for you. Thanks Tom.